# If I change my nickname to my real name, will you start calling me "Thorn"?

Tags: discussion, display-names

This question is very much in jest, but related something that is still continually bugging me. The number of the number of people that can't spell my alias here...

I get called "Lamu" (`l a m u`) [far too often](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1300497) and even though it is an alias, people not calling me by my "name" is something that infuriates me in real life as much as it does here. In real life, people have a habit of calling me by my surname, but without the s at the end; for example calling someone "Michael" when their name is "John Michaels".

I have, however, considered switching to my real name; I use it on my website and other sites, so why not here, but I have an honest question for you all, as my real name is "Thom" does this mean that you're going to start calling me "Thorn"? I'd rather *not* be a thorn if I am honest.

*Note: all those mentions in the linked SEDE are aimed at me. There is only 1 person with the nickname "Larnu" on SO, and only one with the nickname "Lamu"; and the latter hasn't been active since 2015.*

Comment: I had to use +150% of my browser zoom to verify that you are really *larnu* and not *lamu*

Comment: I have to confess I've been among those mispelling your nickname (though only in my mind). It just happens that [Lamu](https://toonitalia.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Lamu-1.jpeg) was a really popular manga/anime character in my childhood...

Comment: I think you should consider that people just get it wrong sometimes. I see it's important to you, but it's not to everyone. It's just someone making a mistake. Everyone has this happen to them. Also note: On small screens it's hard to tell the difference between "rn" and "m".

Comment: I an known around the world as 'James Martin' because of misconfigured MS Outlook displaying my surname first:)

Comment: @Scratte: Is that a serious reply to a question that _"is very much in jest"_? :D

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes :) Some people do get "infuriated", so I just went from there..

Comment: I feel for you there, @MartinJames . I'm so glad my most recent employer doesn't use the `Surname.FirstName@domain` format! 

Comment: Well, people call you by the wrong name because of keming, I've had people spell my name out all weirdly... I usually am just happy that they're at least calling me out...

Comment: I assume the irony was intended, as it's "[kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)" not "[keming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keming)" @BhargavRao ? :)

Comment: You're lookin at the wrong place for the [definition of keming](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Keming).

Comment: The amount of times I get called "John" instead of "Jon" is quite interesting... but ultimately never something to really care about imho

Comment: i had to get ti your profile to see what you mean, with that font it is almost impossible t see that it is rn and not m

Comment: If I could change the font that my name is displayed in, I would be *more* than happy to do so, @nbk :) Maybe I should change my nickname to "Laｒnu"... Hmmm.

Comment: yes you should, it is impossible to see or even remember, but simply correct ot and the user gets a notification and maybe remebers it for the next time.

Comment: @Larnu That'd make it "La-arr-nuu" :D

Comment: There's not actually any spaces there @Cerbrus , it's a [Fullwidth Latin Small Letter R](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/65362) ;)

Comment: @Jon I kindly disagree, unfortunately when someone calls me `@kalido` the notification system fails to match it to my inbox, so sure I don't take any offence for the mispelling, I know the double i is hard to read, but I do see a problem when I miss messages I should have read. IIIRC the notification system is able to pick the correct target even if the mention is incomplete, for as long as there is no non-matching characters attached, just like I did here to you (well I hope). Sounds like the regex could be changed to find Larnu even from `Lamu` if no other nickname starts by `La`

Comment: I am sure there have been many comments I have never responded to, due to users not typing my (5 character) name correctly.

Comment: You could call yourself LARNU.    :p

Comment: I don't want to SHOUT my name at people, @Laurel . :)

Comment: Just rename to @Lar-nu ... if you care to receive notifications. (But do you really care to get notified? There are plenty of people that explicitly pick nicks that can't be typed or otherwise unusable on phones... so I assumed you are just one of them)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My alias is short so that people should be able to easily type it. It's intentionally the opposite.

Comment: People can easily type whatever is auto-completed with current (presumably English) spellchecker/autocomplete they use... everything else is hard. And neither Larnu nor Lamu are English words or common names... It does not look like you are looking to change your nick over that but if you decide to - The Larnu / One Larnu could be another option that is pretty unique (as I don't remember seeing users with such first letters often) and pretty much guarantees  that no one will misspell first 3 letters :)

Comment: Re *"calling me by my surname, but without the s at the end"*: Isn't there a tendency in American English to not pronounce  's' at the end of words (incl. plurals)? (Not a rhetorical question, as I don't live there, but that is the impression I get from podcasts - even from highly-trained professionals in their 50s or 70s)

Comment: I wouldn't know either, @PeterMortensen , I'm English. :)

Comment: Perhaps a native or an expert would care to explain.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to my world...

- Cerberus
- Cerebus
- Ceburs
- Cebrus

Some people even `@`-tag the mentions and don't seem to realize the auto-highlight isn't giving them a suggestion for that name.

Peope will be people, and as we all know, people don't actually read.

---

I was about to suggest a CSS userstyle fix to increase kerning... But that obviously doesn't fix the problem as it won't affect the reader ;-)

That said, it wouldn't take much:

```css
/* Default SO styling */
.username {
  color: rgb(209, 56, 61);
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.kerning {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<span class="username">Larnu</span> Default
<br />
<span class="username kerning">Larnu</span> Readable
```

Comment: I didn't even both looking for non-tags, everything in the SEDE link is "@lamu".

Comment: People also might actually be dyslexic or half blind... just saying...

Comment: @DalijaPransikar: a minority might be. But this extremely serious problem is occurring more than you'd think

Comment: @Dalija I'm currently trying to educate (new) users not to post pictures of code using this comment: _"Can you please tell me what's in that image. Unfortunately I am blind, and my screen reader only spells out gibberish when it comes to that line."_ Some actually started to explain the picture in a reply comment: _"I am very sorry for you. The picture contains a screenshot of my code."_ :-P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I saw some of those comments :)

Comment: @Dalija It worked quite well in a few cases, and OPs copied their code into the question :)

Comment: Fixing kerning would be wrong thing to do. It would just make everything harder to read. Unless you write something in full caps at 24 point size I will still read it wrong. And even then it will be too big, so I will get it wrong again.

Comment: Just for the record, most people cannot properly pronounce my name... don't even let me started with my surname. And yes they will sometimes write it wrong, too. Those are honest mistakes, it makes zero sense to make a big deal out of it (including being infuriated)

Comment: Dah-Lee-Jah Prash-Ni-Kar? :D

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Not to mention my nick ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I always read that as "ravta pei", not "Panta Rhey" :(

Comment: @AndrewT. Did you ever thought of, that it might be intentionally hard to read and ping back ;-)

Comment: The only reason I remember your name is Cerbrus is because there's a totally different user called Cerberus :p

Comment: Something like that... German Da - English Lee - German Ja but I see you are from Netherlands so it might be easier for you. Native English speakers usually pronounce J as J and completely blow it. All other variations are close enough :)

Comment: So in my mind I basically nailed it :D

Comment: on "auto-highlight isn't giving them a suggestion for that name" - @ autocomplete does not work in mobile view (at least on a regular iPhone)... so it is very hard to see if it giving suggestions....

Comment: Reminds me of the profile page of [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar): _“P.S. My name is **barmar**, not **barman**.”_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I always read your nick as "I-have-to-copy-paste-that".